# Kill python script launched by a subprocess called by another script (Windows)

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to integrate ESA'2 sen2cor python-script into my workflow. To do this I create a subprocess with which I call the "L2A_Process.bat" file, which in turn calls the "L2A_Process.py" script.
I want to launch the sen2cor-script with a timeout since it gets stuck and freezes from time to time, so as to automatically re-launch it if it failed.
To launch it and catch a timeout I successfully used the following script:

```
import os, subprocess
from signal import CTRL_BREAK_EVENT

timeout = 3600 #1hour
l1c_safe_path = "path/to/my/input/file.SAFE" #product that I want to process
command = ["L2A_process.bat", l1c_safe_path]
p = subprocess.Popen(command,shell=False, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
try:    
    p.wait(timeout)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:    
    os.kill(p.pid, CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)
```

This is as far as I got. It results in the sen2cor-script being paused  giving the following output:

```
Terminate batch job (Y/N)
```

I'd like to know how I can properly terminate my subprocess "p" with all it own child-subprocesses (i.e. "L2A_Process.py").

Some observations:

- This script needs to run on Windows;
- I've tried to kill the subprocess without the creationflag I've used in the example above: this results in the subprocess being killed but the "L2A_Process.py" script deteaches an keeps running (which is the core of my problem);
- I cannot use a CTRL_C_EVENT  since I want to re-launch the failed "L2A_Process.py" in a loop until it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

**This code works for me to monitor Sen2cor status while converting L1C to L2A for Sentinel 2 data. The Sen2cor process is time and cpu consuming so be patient. It took half an hour to create L2A with DEM, DDV, etc. Hope it helps**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE 
import os

pathtoprodS1C = "path_to_L1C_product"   // safe file 
outdirS2A = "output_dir"                // where L2A files will be placed  
pathtoL2Process = "path_to_L2A_Process" //if not in path

pathtoGIPP = "path_to_your_GIPP/L2A_GIPP.xml"

procName = "./L2A_Process"

os.chdir(pathtoL2Process)
import shlex
pcall = "./{} {} --output_dir {} --tif --GIP_L2A {}".format(procName, 
                                                pathtoprodS1C, 
                                                pathtoprodS2A,
                                                pathtoGIPP)
args = shlex.split(pcall)
print(args)
try:
    p = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE)
    eut = p.stdout.readline()
    while eut:
        eut = p.stdout.readline()
        print(eut)
finally:
    print('Sen2Cor is Done')
    
exit()
```